# How to undo edit of QStandardItem in PySide/PyQt?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

Using the [identical question asked about QListWidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954565/how-to-undo-an-edit-of-a-qlistwidgetitem-in-pyside-pyqt) as a guide, I am trying to make a `QStandardItemModel` in which I can undo the edit of an item.

As can be seen in the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) below, I'm pretty much copying the example exactly, but with some minor tweaking because `currentItemChanged` isn't available for `QStandardItemModel`. To get around that, I'm using the `clicked` signal instead to fix the previous text for an item.

Strangely, the correct description shows up in the undostack, but when I click the `undo` button it doesn't actually undo anything.

Note the present question is superficially the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899735/qtableview-qstandarditemmodel-revert-or-undo-user-entry). The answer that was accepted at that other version is less an answer, more a hint. It's a hint I am trying to implement here, but it is not working yet. Since this question is more specific and detailed, it shouldn't count as a duplicate, IMO.

**SSCCE**

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class CommandItemEdit(QtGui.QUndoCommand):
    def __init__(self, model, item, textBeforeEdit, description = "Item edited"):
        QtGui.QUndoCommand.__init__(self, description)
        self.model = model
        self.item = item
        self.textBeforeEdit = textBeforeEdit
        self.textAfterEdit = item.text()

    def redo(self):
        self.model.blockSignals(True)  
        self.item.setText(self.textAfterEdit)
        self.model.blockSignals(False)

    def undo(self):
        self.model.blockSignals(True)
        self.item.setText(self.textBeforeEdit)
        self.model.blockSignals(False)     


class UndoableTree(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent = None)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.view = QtGui.QTreeView()
        self.model = self.createModel()
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.view.expandAll()
        self.undoStack = QtGui.QUndoStack(self)
        undoView = QtGui.QUndoView(self.undoStack)
        buttonLayout = self.buttonSetup()
        mainLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        mainLayout.addWidget(undoView)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.view)
        mainLayout.addLayout(buttonLayout)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.makeConnections()
        #For undo/redo editing
        self.textBeforeEdit = ""

    def makeConnections(self):
        self.view.clicked.connect(self.itemClicked)
        self.model.itemChanged.connect(self.itemChanged)
        self.quitButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.undoButton.clicked.connect(self.undoStack.undo)
        self.redoButton.clicked.connect(self.undoStack.redo)

    def itemClicked(self, index):
        item = self.model.itemFromIndex(index)
        self.textBeforeEdit = item.text()  

    def itemChanged(self, item):
        command = CommandItemEdit(self.model, item, self.textBeforeEdit, 
            "Renamed '{0}' to '{1}'".format(self.textBeforeEdit, item.text()))
        self.undoStack.push(command)


    def buttonSetup(self):
        self.undoButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Undo")
        self.redoButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Redo")
        self.quitButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Quit")
        buttonLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout.addStretch()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.undoButton)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.redoButton)
        buttonLayout.addStretch()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.quitButton)
        return buttonLayout

    def createModel(self):
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Titles', 'Summaries'])
        rootItem = model.invisibleRootItem()
        #First top-level row and children 
        item0 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Title0'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Summary0')]
        item00 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Title00'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Summary00')]
        item01 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Title01'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Summary01')]
        rootItem.appendRow(item0)
        item0[0].appendRow(item00)
        item0[0].appendRow(item01)
        #Second top-level item and its children
        item1 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Title1'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Summary1')]
        item10 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Title10'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Summary10')]
        item11 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Title11'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Summary11')]
        rootItem.appendRow(item1)
        item1[0].appendRow(item10)
        item1[0].appendRow(item11)

        return model


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    newTree = UndoableTree()
    newTree.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I don't mean to be too annoying about this, but the definition of SSCCE you link to specifically states that the example code should be **self-contained**. Telling people to go to another question, copy and **rename** another class, and include it with the code from this question, doesn't exactly make it self contained!

Comment: Actually I'm more confused now. The code for `CommandItemEdit` class is not contained within the other question. There is code for a `CommandEdit` class, but it takes a different number of instantiation arguments. **What code are you actually using?**

Comment: @three_pineapples oops I meant to put that back in before posting, and somehow neglected to. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [quote another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29659545/1886357) at a closely related question :

> The clicked signal seems to be entirely the wrong way to track
>   changes. How are you going to deal with changes made via the keyboard?
>   And what about changes that are made programmatically? For an undo
>   stack to work correctly, every change has to be recorded, and in
>   exactly the same order that it was made.

The same post went on to suggest creating a custom signal that emits old/new data when the data are actually changed. Ultimately I used three ideas that I stole shamelessly from SO. First, [three_pineapples' insight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29561691/1886357) that `disconnect` is needed to avoid infinite recursion. Second, subclass `QStandardItemModel` to define a new `itemDataChanged` signal that sends both previous and new data to a slot. Third, subclass `QStandardItem` and have it emit this signal when the data is changed: this is handled in a reimplementation of `setData()`).

Here is the full code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class CommandTextEdit(QtGui.QUndoCommand):
    def __init__(self, tree, item, oldText, newText, description):
        QtGui.QUndoCommand.__init__(self, description)
        self.item = item
        self.tree = tree
        self.oldText = oldText
        self.newText = newText

    def redo(self):      
        self.item.model().itemDataChanged.disconnect(self.tree.itemDataChangedSlot) 
        self.item.setText(self.newText)
        self.item.model().itemDataChanged.connect(self.tree.itemDataChangedSlot) 

    def undo(self):
        self.item.model().itemDataChanged.disconnect(self.tree.itemDataChangedSlot) 
        self.item.setText(self.oldText)
        self.item.model().itemDataChanged.connect(self.tree.itemDataChangedSlot) 


class CommandCheckStateChange(QtGui.QUndoCommand):
    def __init__(self, tree, item, oldCheckState, newCheckState, description):
        QtGui.QUndoCommand.__init__(self, description)
        self.item = item
        self.tree = tree
        self.oldCheckState = QtCore.Qt.Unchecked if oldCheckState == 0 else QtCore.Qt.Checked
        self.newCheckState = QtCore.Qt.Checked if oldCheckState == 0 else QtCore.Qt.Unchecked

    def redo(self): #disoconnect to avoid recursive loop b/w signal-slot
        self.item.model().itemDataChanged.disconnect(self.tree.itemDataChangedSlot) 
        self.item.setCheckState(self.newCheckState)
        self.item.model().itemDataChanged.connect(self.tree.itemDataChangedSlot) 

    def undo(self):
        self.item.model().itemDataChanged.disconnect(self.tree.itemDataChangedSlot)
        self.item.setCheckState(self.oldCheckState)
        self.item.model().itemDataChanged.connect(self.tree.itemDataChangedSlot) 


class StandardItemModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    itemDataChanged = QtCore.Signal(object, object, object, object)


class StandardItem(QtGui.QStandardItem):
    def setData(self, newValue, role=QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            oldValue = self.data(role)
            QtGui.QStandardItem.setData(self, newValue, role)
            model = self.model()
            #only emit signal if newvalue is different from old
            if model is not None and oldValue != newValue:
                model.itemDataChanged.emit(self, oldValue, newValue, role)
            return True
        if role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole:
            oldValue = self.data(role)
            QtGui.QStandardItem.setData(self, newValue, role)
            model = self.model()
            if model is not None and oldValue != newValue:
                model.itemDataChanged.emit(self, oldValue, newValue, role)
            return True
        QtGui.QStandardItem.setData(self, newValue, role)


class UndoableTree(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent = None)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.view = QtGui.QTreeView()
        self.model = self.createModel()
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.view.expandAll()
        self.undoStack = QtGui.QUndoStack(self)
        undoView = QtGui.QUndoView(self.undoStack)
        buttonLayout = self.buttonSetup()
        mainLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        mainLayout.addWidget(undoView)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.view)
        mainLayout.addLayout(buttonLayout)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.makeConnections()

    def makeConnections(self):
        self.model.itemDataChanged.connect(self.itemDataChangedSlot)
        self.quitButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.undoButton.clicked.connect(self.undoStack.undo)
        self.redoButton.clicked.connect(self.undoStack.redo)

    def itemDataChangedSlot(self, item, oldValue, newValue, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            command = CommandTextEdit(self, item, oldValue, newValue,
                "Text changed from '{0}' to '{1}'".format(oldValue, newValue))
            self.undoStack.push(command)
            return True
        if role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole:
            command = CommandCheckStateChange(self, item, oldValue, newValue, 
                "CheckState changed from '{0}' to '{1}'".format(oldValue, newValue))
            self.undoStack.push(command)
            return True

    def buttonSetup(self):
        self.undoButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Undo")
        self.redoButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Redo")
        self.quitButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Quit")
        buttonLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout.addStretch()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.undoButton)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.redoButton)
        buttonLayout.addStretch()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.quitButton)
        return buttonLayout

    def createModel(self):
        model = StandardItemModel()
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Titles', 'Summaries'])
        rootItem = model.invisibleRootItem()
        item0 = [StandardItem('Title0'), StandardItem('Summary0')]
        item00 = [StandardItem('Title00'), StandardItem('Summary00')]
        item01 = [StandardItem('Title01'), StandardItem('Summary01')]
        item0[0].setCheckable(True)
        item00[0].setCheckable(True)
        item01[0].setCheckable(True)
        rootItem.appendRow(item0)
        item0[0].appendRow(item00)
        item0[0].appendRow(item01)
        return model


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    newTree = UndoableTree()
    newTree.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Overall, this seems better than using `clicked`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to arise because `blockSignals()` is preventing the treeview from being told to repaint. I think this is because the model emits a signal to the treeview when data in the model is modified, which is obviously being blocked when you call `model.blockSignals(True)`. If you manually resize the window after clicking undo/redo (obviously only works if there is something to undo/redo), you see that the undo/redo has actually been applied, it just didn't initially show it.

To work around this, I've modified the code so that instead of blocking signals, we disconnect the relevant signal and reconnect it. This allows the model and treeview to continue to communicate correctly while the undo/redo is in progress.

See the below code

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class CommandItemEdit(QtGui.QUndoCommand):
    def __init__(self, connectSignals, disconnectSignals, model, item, textBeforeEdit, description = "Item edited"):
        QtGui.QUndoCommand.__init__(self, description)
        self.model = model
        self.item = item
        self.textBeforeEdit = textBeforeEdit
        self.textAfterEdit = item.text()
        self.connectSignals = connectSignals
        self.disconnectSignals = disconnectSignals

    def redo(self):
        self.disconnectSignals()
        self.item.setText(self.textAfterEdit)
        self.connectSignals()

    def undo(self):
        self.disconnectSignals()
        self.item.setText(self.textBeforeEdit)
        self.connectSignals()


class UndoableTree(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent = None)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.view = QtGui.QTreeView()
        self.model = self.createModel()
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.view.expandAll()
        self.undoStack = QtGui.QUndoStack(self)
        undoView = QtGui.QUndoView(self.undoStack)
        buttonLayout = self.buttonSetup()
        mainLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        mainLayout.addWidget(undoView)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.view)
        mainLayout.addLayout(buttonLayout)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.makeConnections()
        #For undo/redo editing
        self.textBeforeEdit = ""

    def makeConnections(self):
        self.view.clicked.connect(self.itemClicked)
        self.model.itemChanged.connect(self.itemChanged)
        self.quitButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.undoButton.clicked.connect(self.undoStack.undo)
        self.redoButton.clicked.connect(self.undoStack.redo)

    def disconnectSignal(self):    
        self.model.itemChanged.disconnect(self.itemChanged)

    def connectSignal(self):
        self.model.itemChanged.connect(self.itemChanged)

    def itemClicked(self, index):
        item = self.model.itemFromIndex(index)
        self.textBeforeEdit = item.text()  

    def itemChanged(self, item):
        command = CommandItemEdit(self.connectSignal, self.disconnectSignal, self.model, item, self.textBeforeEdit, 
            "Renamed '{0}' to '{1}'".format(self.textBeforeEdit, item.text()))
        self.undoStack.push(command)


    def buttonSetup(self):
        self.undoButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Undo")
        self.redoButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Redo")
        self.quitButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Quit")
        buttonLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout.addStretch()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.undoButton)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.redoButton)
        buttonLayout.addStretch()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.quitButton)
        return buttonLayout

    def createModel(self):
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Titles', 'Summaries'])
        rootItem = model.invisibleRootItem()
        #First top-level row and children 
        item0 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Title0'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Summary0')]
        item00 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Title00'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Summary00')]
        item01 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Title01'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Summary01')]
        rootItem.appendRow(item0)
        item0[0].appendRow(item00)
        item0[0].appendRow(item01)
        #Second top-level item and its children
        item1 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Title1'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Summary1')]
        item10 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Title10'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Summary10')]
        item11 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Title11'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Summary11')]
        rootItem.appendRow(item1)
        item1[0].appendRow(item10)
        item1[0].appendRow(item11)

        return model


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    newTree = UndoableTree()
    newTree.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Additional Information

I've discovered that you could use you original implementation of `CommandItemEdit` if you explicitly call `self.model.layoutChanged.emit()` after unblocking the signals. This forces the treeview to update without resulting in a call to the `UndoableTree.itemChanged()` slot.

Note, the treeview is connected to the model signals, while the treeview is in turn connected to the `UndoableTree.itemChanged()` slot.

I also tried emitting the `dataChanged()` signal, but this ends up ultimately calling the still connected `UndoableTree.itemChanged()` slot, which results in infinite recursion. I think this is signal is the target of the call to `model.blockSignals()`, so it makes sense not to call it explicitly!

So in the end, while one of these additional methods does work, I would still go with my first answer of explicitly disconnecting the signal. This is simply because I think it is better to leave communication between the model and treeview completely intact, rather than restrict some communication while manually triggering the signals you still want. The latter route is likely to have unintended side-effects and be a pain to debug.

Comment: 1. Great find that the model was actually modified, as shown when you force a redraw by resizing. 2. I have been doing PySide for a while, and never knew there was a 'disconnect' method, so something new here to learn. 3. Is there a reason you chose this technique rather than the naive approach of just calling repaint (or update) within the undo/redo methods? (Note I just tried updating the view in the redo/undo, by adding update, or repaint, to the old code, and it did nothing...I don't understand why).

Comment: I chose this technique because `repaint()` and `update()` didn't work! I don't know why, but I've never had much success getting those methods to do what I want with a `QWidget`. I've also updated the answer with a little bit more information I've just discovered.

Comment: The update you added is very helpful, especially trying `dataChanged()`, which would seem a natural solution. Strange that such a simple undo operation is so complicated!

Comment: I'm now trying to implement with checkboxes, so both the check operation and text editing can be undone. Will become a separate question, though already has to some degree: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640408/how-to-treat-click-events-differently-for-an-items-checkbox-versus-its-text-p